# Prevent loss of Large Signal Voltage Gain at low Rload

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-power, gain

Operational Amplifiers (opamps) have the tendency to drop their Large Signal Voltage Gain when the load is too low. This behaviour is usually described in the datasheet. Loads of 500 ohm and lower usually result in very low gain.

How can I prevent this loss of gain?

I've tried using another opamp as a unity buffer, but the top of the signal gets clipped. I've tried a transistor, but the signal got distorted. My target load is 50 ohm and the signal is a triangle in 50 - 10000 Hz range, 0 - 10 V. The opamps in use are LT1077.

EDIT: I'm aware of the trouble the LT1077 has at low loads. I'd hoped there would be a buffer solution like I tried with the transistor (as far as I know though, Class A are used when the load gets too heavy, not when too low).

When trying the transistor, the top of the signal got clipped. I made sure there was enough voltage available, so I'm not sure how that happened.

Comment: Use an op amp or buffer with very low output impedance.

Comment: In what way is (a) the transistor distorting the signal or (b) the OPA350 not keeping it intact? Better to diagnose and correct the defects than blindly swap components until it works. An opamp driving a transistor ought to be viable, if you have the power budget to use the transistor as a Class A output stage. If power is an issue, the design gets more complex.

Comment: Out of interest, what is your load? 50 ohm is quite a low load, are you driving a loudspeaker?

Comment: @Oliver No, a K-band radar module. And indeed, 50 is low. That's probably why I never encountered this problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an opamp with more output current.  Search for power opamps. (LM675 and OPA544 are two I've used.) At 200mA you might get away with a TCA0372.   Or use some audio driver chips if you don't care about DC.

Edit:(more thoughts, comments)  Warning the LM675 has a minimum gain of 10.  And all the power opamps I've looked at have some cross-over distortion. (Still looking for the perfect power opamp.)  If your output is single sided, then you could use a transistor (Class A) with the transistor in the opamp feedback loop.. but that will waste a lot of power.  Or make you own push-pull output stage.  (again as part of the opamp feed back loop)

Comment: I've tried multiple opamps and by luck had an OPA350 laying around. Works much better than the LT1077, but doesn't keep the signal intact. I'm working single sided, but noise/distortion is a problem with high power opamps.

Comment: @Mast, At 10V it's hard to believe that the noise of the OPA544 would be a problem.  But you could use it at unity gain and stick your nice low noise opamp in front of it.  If cross over distortion is your concern, then a power wasting class A transistor/opamp would work. (I could scribble something if you don't know what I'm talking about.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different op amp to drive a \$50\Omega\$ load.

Page 8 of the [LT1077 datasheet](http://www.linear.com/docs/2472) shows the following plot:

[image]

\$50\Omega\$ load resistance isn't even on the plot, and the voltage gain is quite low even for load resistances in the \$1\$k\$\Omega\$ range.

Also, the output impedance is not great (especially considering a \$50\Omega\$ load):

[image]